# How can i solve that Calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a calculation in which i get result but some issue in after Decimal 
   Place which is:

```
(31,250x.04) / ((1 + .04)^16.5)-1 = 1,373.52 (this is the original answer)
```

But when i calculate i get 1,373.626373. So can any one help me to solve it
   My Calculation is this:

select (31250 * .04) = 1250.00

select POWER((1.04),16.5)-1  = 0.91

select 1250.00/0.91

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using?

Comment: My sql version is SQL Server 2012.

Comment: SQLITE has a ROUND() function that lets you set the number of digits after the decimal point. Google says SQL SERVER does also.

Comment: can u send me a solution to this.

Comment: You might want to handle this in your presentation layer.

Comment: i cant understand what u say can u give me solution

Comment: Out of interest where did you do the original calculation to get a result of 1373.52?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast to better-than-default precision for number literals to get all the digits of the `0.91007...` term:

```
select convert(decimal(18,9), 31250 * 0.04) / (convert(decimal(18,9), power(convert(decimal(18,9), 1 + 0.04), 16.5))-1)
```

Compare all results using

```
select convert(real, 31250 * 0.04) / (convert(real, power(1 + 0.04, 16.5))-1)

select convert(float, 31250 * 0.04) / (convert(float, power(1 + 0.04, 16.5))-1)

select convert(decimal(18,9), 31250 * 0.04) / (convert(decimal(18,9), power(convert(decimal(18,9), 1 + 0.04), 16.5))-1)
```